# Phaser Collision not working as expected in Arcade

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-engine, game-physics, phaser-framework

I have a **man sprite** (man) and a group of **tree sprites** (trees) setup with collision like this:

> this.game.physics.arcade.collide(man,trees);

It works fine for the most part EXCEPT the man can walk UP into the tree (see below). Collision detect is working fine in all other directions (LEFT, RIGHT and DOWN, but not UP). Is this a bug? Gravity related or am i doing something wrong.

[image]

See Video: http://screencast.com/t/j5tLsqpO

Comment: check out this: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/5966-arcade-collision-only-from-one-direction/. maybe your upward collision was turned off

Comment: I have doubled checked and nothing is turned off. Also tried explicitly setting it (but makes no difference): tree.body.checkCollision.up = true;
         tree.body.checkCollision.left = true;
   tree.body.checkCollision.right = true;
   tree.body.checkCollision.down = true;

Comment: I checked out the link and it seems describe the same or similar problem but I can't seem to find any solutions referenced

Comment: Found the problem, in my update routine had a little bug: was using: man.body.y to move him vs man.body.velocity.y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to use **man.body.velocity.y** and NOT **man.body.y** in update routine